# Pydub split on silence has no output

Tags: python, python-3.5, pydub

I am completely blank here. I have a wav file (tried multiple files from multiple sources) which I am trying to split on basis of silence between words using pydub.silence.split_on_silence method. Whatever I do, I don't get any output, I mean none.
File is read using Audiosegment. I export the original file as well just to make sure file is read properly and the exported files I just fine. But no splitted wavs.
I am using Python 3.5.2

```
sound_file = AudioSegment.from_wav(path)
sound_file.export('inputfile.wav', format="wav")
audio_chunks = pydub.silence.split_on_silence(sound_file)
print("Audio chunks generated ", audio_chunks)
```

Print of audio_chunks result in [] instead of showing array of objects.
There is no error thrown.

Comment: is it possible that the entire audio file is below the threshold to be considered silent (i.e., with the definition of “Silent” being used, there is no content, only silence)

Comment: Not sure how to check that, but pretty sure that isnt the case. The recording is pretty loud and I have tried tweaking the default silence threshold, changing frmo -16 to -25 also, and still nothing.

Comment: have you tried playing with the min_silence_len parameter? The lower it is, the more opportunity there is to find chunks of sound.